# 1959 White Sox World Series roster

Tags: baseball

I thought the roster for the 1959 WHITE SOX  World Series had  25 players.  I can find stats on the 21  that played and   I  have found  3 that did not get into a game (Battey, Latman,  Arias) .  Was there  a 25th  player????

Comment: I don't see any site that lists the entire roster specifically for the World Series at least in a brief check.

Comment: What site did you use for the initial 25 number? And where did you find the 3 who did not play? And are you including pitchers?

Comment: baseball-reference.com. They like all other sites show stats on 21 players who got into a game for the Sox during the 1959 World Series.  The Sox could not answer my question, they sent me a list of 40 who played for the Sox during the entire 1959 season. They have not responded to a follow-up  .  The Hall of Fame - Cooperstown sent me 1959 White Sox World Series Program showing all 25. The 4 not seeing any playing time were Battey , Arias , Moore,  and Mcbride.  Sabr.org ( society for American Baseball Research has an INCORRECT bio  on Mcbride (" left off the post season roster")Steve Fox

Comment: Wow! Amazing work Steve Fox! I didn't ask this question but was glad to see someone found some good info.

Comment: Thanks Paul . After contacting SABR.org ,they confirmed this with reference from the Chicago Tribune and thanked me and would contact their webmaster for a correction to Mcbride's bio. The Hall of Fame  was very friendly and helpful. (not the Sox or Dodgers)

Answer (score 1):

Steve Fox-
You almost got them. Moore did play as a reliever in game six (ninth inning) and Latman didn't play at all. So, Battey, Latman, Arias, and McBride didn't play.

Comment: If you can you should add a reference to where you found this

Comment: Thanks Keith, you are the only one in almost a year that noticed my error. I did notice it when I reread it later  but never bothered to correct . It is  very apparent , because all the websites do show the 21 players that got into a game for the Sox in the 1959 Series. Also SABR has still not corrected  Mcbride's bio( " left off the post season roster")  Great work . THANKS again.     Steve Fox